# how to verify array list WebElement in selenium greater and lowest value

Tags: java, selenium, arraylist, automated-tests

website is dark sky and I want to verify current temp is greater or less than temps from timeline. I used array list. I need to get current temp and compare it with them. Thank you. I couldn’t do that. Do u have any idea for this. Thnx.

```
ArrayList<WebElement> list = new ArrayList<>(SharedSD.getDriver( ).findElements(greaterOrLess));
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55274122/verify-current-temp-is-not-greater-or-less-then-temps-from-daily-timeline

Comment: Possible duplicate of [verify current temp is not greater or less then temps from daily timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55274122/verify-current-temp-is-not-greater-or-less-then-temps-from-daily-timeline)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DarkSky considered for test:

[image]

Python Script on darksky:

[image]

Just converted the python code to java

```
driver.get("https://darksky.net/forecast/40.7127,-74.0059/us12/en");
String currentTemp = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".summary.swap")).getText();
System.out.println("Current Temp:" + currentTemp);
List<WebElement> tempsInTimeLine = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".temps span:last-child"));
int temp = Integer.parseInt(currentTemp.substring(0, 2));
int highestInTimeLine = temp;
int lowestInTimeLine = temp;
for (WebElement tempInTime: tempsInTimeLine) {
    String sLIneTemp = tempInTime.getText();
    int lineTemp = Integer.parseInt(sLIneTemp.substring(0, 2));
    if (lineTemp > highestInTimeLine){
        highestInTimeLine  = lineTemp;
    }
    if (lineTemp < lowestInTimeLine ){
        lowestInTimeLine = lineTemp;
    }

}

System.out.println("Highest Temp:" + Integer.toString(highestInTimeLine));
System.out.println("Lowest Temp:" + Integer.toString(lowestInTimeLine ));
```

Comment: sorry I need reputation to talk with you :))

Comment: I think the problem same line and substring causes the error. I tried several ways, it didn't happen                                        java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

Comment: Updated the code. I am sure this will work, trust me :-) as I ran the code.